# Flask context processors functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

Following the minimal example on the Flask pages I'm trying to build a context processor:

context_procesor.py

```
def inflect_this():
    def inflectorize(number, word):
        return "{} {}".format(number, inflectorizor.plural(word, number))
    return dict(inflectorize=inflectorize)
```

app.py(within an app factory)

```
from context_processor import inflect_this

app.context_processor(inflect_this)
```

Using a previous inflection function that inflects a word based on number, simple I already have it as a jinja filter but wanted to see if I could do it as a context processor.

Given the example at the bootom of the page here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/, this should work but does not. I get:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError UndefinedError: 'inflectorize' is undefined
```

I do not understand enough you to see what is going on. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

EDIT:

```
app.jinja_env.globals.update(inflectorize=inflectorize)
```

works to add functions and seems to be less overhead than wrapping a method in a method, where app.context_processor probably relays to jinja_env.globals anyway.

Comment: Did you try using the decorator `@app.context_processor` to decorate `inflect_this`? It should be the same thing, but might be worth a try.

Comment: I'm importing this from a file and using an appfactory, so 'app' isn't available and throws a name error if the decorator is used. I'm trying to do this more as an extension would. I think I could do a blueprint and then import that, but that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: If `app` isn't available then how do you add `inflect_this` via `app.context_processor`?  What is `app` in your example then?

Comment: It is in a different file, the above edited for clarification.

Comment: Is the "EDIT" at the end the answer you settled on? Please post it separately as an answer if you intended it to be one.

Answer (score 22):

I'm not sure if this entirely answers your question, as I haven't used app factories.

However, I tried this from a blueprint, and this works for me. You just have to use the blueprint object in the decorator instead of the default "app":

thingy/view.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

thingy = Blueprint("thingy", __name__, template_folder='templates')

@thingy.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template("thingy_test.html")

@thingy.context_processor
def utility_processor():
  def format_price(amount, currency=u'$'):
    return u'{1}{0:.2f}'.format(amount, currency)
  return dict(format_price=format_price)
```

templates/thingy_test.html

```
<h1> {{ format_price(0.33) }}</h1>
```

and I see the expected "$0.33" in the template.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Seems like this would work and what I had intended to test, but have not returned to this piece of code in my project yet.

Comment: +1 for the hint that the `context_processor` decorator works for Blueprints as well as for Flask instances.

Comment: If I have more than one function that has to be made a context_processor. How should i be defining it in my Python Flask File

Comment: @Antu You can place your functions inside of your context_processor wrapper (ie utility_processor() in the example above), or create multiple wrapper functions with each one decorated with \@app.context_processor

Comment: @Antu define all the functions you want inside *utility_processor* and then utility processor should return a dict which contains all the functions you want to use in your templates . If you didn't get the point, ask a new question let the community answer you . (let me know if you did:) )

Comment: @RachelSanders, do you know how to use this context_processor in another blueprint if i don't want to copy/paste twice. Thx

Comment: How can we write unit test for the above solution, any suggestion please?