# How to put decorators on `app` when using Application Factory with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators

I'm trying to define some global constants for my app, and have found that this can be done with a function that's decorated as `@app.context_processor`.

However, the issue is that I don't have an `app` variable. My application uses an application factory, and I'd like to keep it that way. Is there a different way to register a function as the `context_processor` for my app?

One option I have seen is to apply the decorator to each `Blueprint` instead of applying it to the app. That's something I would like to avoid though, since it would lead to a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask context processors functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809890/flask-context-processors-functions)

Comment: Thanks @IMCoins, but that is a question I had already run into. The answer explains how you can decorate each individual blueprint, which would result in a lot of redundant code for me.

Comment: So you are using blueprints? Also is that you want to use decorators only or are you ok to register them later through code?

Comment: add the code you have tried ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that there is no `app` object in case of factories. You have a `create_app` function where the app gets created.

So to install the context processors you can use `create_app` itself

```py
def create_app(config_filename):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)

    from yourapplication.model import db
    db.init_app(app)

    from yourapplication.context_processor import myprocessor
    app.context_processor(myprocessor)

    from yourapplication.views.frontend import frontend
    app.register_blueprint(frontend)

    return app
```

You could also have the function in the same app.py file (wherever the create_app() function is written). In such a case, you could simply register the context_processor without importing it.

Another approach is to do it in a blueprint as shown in below

[Flask context processors functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809890/flask-context-processors-functions)

```py
from flask import Blueprint

thingy = Blueprint("thingy", __name__, template_folder='templates')

@thingy.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template("thingy_test.html")

@thingy.context_processor
def utility_processor():
  def format_price(amount, currency=u'$'):
    return u'{1}{0:.2f}'.format(amount, currency)
  return dict(format_price=format_price)
```

Comment: Thank you! Am I correct to assume that `myprocessor` in your first code sample is a function that takes no arguments, similar to the function in your second example?

Comment: @LeeWhite, yes, basically the processor function you had written in some other file without the decorator

Comment: Just gave it a try and it worked like a charm. Thanks so much!